# How to destroy a parent window when child window's red X is clicked in Tkinter 8.5 and Python 3.3

Tags: python, tkinter

Newbie question here. I would like for `secondWindow` to be destroyed in addition to `thirdWindow` when the red X is clicked in `thirdWindow`, just like what happens when you click `thirdButton` in `thirdWindow`. `firstWindow` should remain alive.

Below is some example code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk 

def secondWindow():
    secondWindow = tkinter.Toplevel(firstWindow)
    secondFrame = ttk.Frame(secondWindow)
    secondFrame.pack()
    secondButton = ttk.Button(secondFrame, text="proceed to 3rd window",\
                              command=lambda: thirdWindow(secondWindow))
    secondButton.pack()

def thirdWindow(parent):
    thirdWindow = tkinter.Toplevel(parent)
    thirdFrame = ttk.Frame(thirdWindow)
    thirdFrame.pack()
    thirdButton = ttk.Button(thirdFrame, text="close 2nd and 3rd windows",\
                             command=lambda: destroy(thirdWindow, parent))
    thirdButton.pack()

def destroy(self, parent):
    self.destroy()
    parent.destroy()

firstWindow = tkinter.Tk()
firstFrame = ttk.Frame(firstWindow)
firstFrame.pack()
firstButton = ttk.Button(firstFrame, text="proceed to 2nd window",\
                         command=secondWindow)
firstButton.pack()
firstWindow.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding `thirdWindow.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: destroy(thirdWindow, parent))` to the `thirdWindow()` function seems to have done the trick.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Lal I'm not sure what you mean. The above code does exactly what I set out to do - use a child's red X button to kill itself AND it's parent (but not it's grandparent). Maybe my question was unclear somehow?

Comment: Your answer may be correct..I Commented on this because it was flagged as a low quality post..

Answer (score 0):

Use `parent` to run `parent` function or get variable from `parent` - for example to get its `parent` or run function which close its parent.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk 

def secondWindow(parent):
    secondWindow = tkinter.Toplevel(parent)
    secondWindow.parent = parent # remember parent

    secondFrame = ttk.Frame(secondWindow)
    secondFrame.pack()
    secondButton = ttk.Button(secondFrame, text="proceed to 3rd window",\
                              command=lambda: thirdWindow(secondWindow))
    secondButton.pack()

def thirdWindow(parent):
    thirdWindow = tkinter.Toplevel(parent)
    thirdWindow.parent = parent # remember parent

    thirdFrame = ttk.Frame(thirdWindow)
    thirdFrame.pack()
    thirdButton = ttk.Button(thirdFrame, text="close 2nd and 3rd windows",\
                             command=lambda: destroy(thirdWindow))
    thirdButton.pack()

def destroy(self):
    self.parent.parent.destroy()  # destroy grand-parent and all children are dead too.

firstWindow = tkinter.Tk()
firstFrame = ttk.Frame(firstWindow)
firstFrame.pack()
firstButton = ttk.Button(firstFrame, text="proceed to 2nd window",\
                         command=lambda:secondWindow(firstWindow))
firstButton.pack()
firstWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: When I run this code it doesn't do what I expect. I want exiting out of the third window (either by clicking the button or red X) to kill ONLY its parent window (`secondWindow`), without killing `firstWindow`.

Comment: Do you want to kill second window and keep third open ? I think you can't. Parent always kills childred. Or rather `garbage collector` clear memory and remove it.

Comment: Sorry, clarification: exiting out of the third window (by clicking button or red X) should kill it's parent and itself, but NOT the grandparent window (firstwindow)

Comment: Strange. I run your code and it close third windows and its parent. So there is nothing to do.